# How to use save() method inside a loop in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

My current situation is: I must use save() method to save multiple records using loop. I know insert() will fix my problem but to maintain my code clean I have to use the same code and save() method to insert the record. I create new instance inside the loop but always only last record is being inserted. My code looks like:

```
  public static function save($data)
    {
       
        $settings       =  Settings::instance();
        $data['sender_address'] = urldecode($data['sender_address']);
        $data['sender_address'] = json_decode($data['sender_address'], true);
        
        extract($data);
        $customerFields = ['name', 'mobile', 'alt_mobile', 'district_id', 'area_id', 'address'];
        $customerObj = $customer =  Customer::where('mobile', $mobile);
        if ($customerObj->count()) {
            $customer =  $customer->first();
        } else {
            $customer = new Customer;
        }
        foreach ($customerFields as $customerField) {
            if (!empty($$customerField)) {
                $customer->$customerField = $$customerField;
            }
        }
        ($customerObj->count()) ? $customer->update() : $customer->save();
        
        $order =  (isset($order_id) && !empty($order_id) )? Order::find($order_id) : new Order;
        $order->sender_address = $sender_address;
        $order->branch_id = self::getBranchIdByAreaId($sender_address['area']);
        $order->responsible_by = self::getBranchManagerIdByBranchId($order->branch_id);
        $order->client_id = $client_id;
        $order->customer_id = $customer->id;
        $order->delivery_time = $delivery_time;
        $deliveryChargeParams = [
            'district_id' => $district_id,
            'delivery_time' => $delivery_time,
            'product_weight' => $product_weight,
            'merchant_id' => $client_id,
        ];
        
        $order->delivery_charge = Utility::getDeliveryCharge($deliveryChargeParams);
        $order->vat = Utility::getVat($order->delivery_charge);

        if (empty($order_id)) {

            $order->status_id = ($role_id == Employee::CLIENT) ?
                $settings['tracking']['default_status'] : Order::PACKAGINGDONE;

            if (($role_id != Employee::CLIENT)) {
                $order->requested =  Order::PACKAGINGDONE;
            }
        }

        $order->cash_amount = $cash_amount;
        $order->cod_charge = Utility::getCodCharge($cash_amount);
        $order->product_weight = $product_weight;
        $order->client_reference = $client_reference;
     
        if (empty($order_id)) {
           
            $order->save();
            $loggedInUserId = isset($data['fromApp'])? 
                               $data['client_id'] : Auth::getUser()->id;
            $order->number  = self::orderNumber($order,$loggedInUserId);
            $order->update();
            
        } else {
            $order->update();
        }
        if (($role_id != Employee::CLIENT)) {
            self::updateDeliveryWithin($order);
        }
        PaymentAction::update($order);
    }
```

The following method calls this save() method:

```
function onSave(){
    $data = post();
    $client_id = (Auth::getUser()->role_id == Employee::CLIENT) ? Auth::getUser()->id : $data['client_id'];

    $sender_address = $data['sender_address'];
    $file = Input::file('bulk_order');
    
    $filename = time().'-'.rand(2000,99999999).'-'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
    $result = $file->move('tempFiles',$filename);
    $uploadedFilePath = 'tempFiles/'.$filename;
    $contents = $this->csvToArray($uploadedFilePath);
   // dd($contents); //exit;
    unlink($uploadedFilePath);
    $keys = array();
    if(count($contents)){
        $keys = array_keys($contents[0]);
    }else{
         throw new ApplicationException('Your Csv file is not in proper Format OR Empty!');
    }

    $fields = array('client_reference','customer_mobile','customer_alternative_mobile','customer_name','customer_district','customer_area','customer_address','product_weight_in_kg','delivery_time_in_hour','cash_collection');
    $diff = array_diff($keys,$fields);
   
    //dd($diff); exit;
    if(count($diff)!=0){
         throw new ApplicationException('Your Csv file is not in proper Format');
    }
     //   dd($contents);    exit;
    foreach($contents as $row){

       $data['name'] = $row['customer_name'];
       $data['mobile'] = $row['customer_mobile'];

      if(strlen($data['mobile']) == 10 ){
        $data['mobile'] = '0'.$data['mobile'];
      }
      $data['alt_mobile'] = $row['customer_alternative_mobile'];
      if(strlen($data['alt_mobile']) == 10 ){
        $data['alt_mobile'] = '0'.$data['alt_mobile'];
      }

       $data['district_id'] = Utility::getDistrictIdByName($row['customer_district']);
       $data['area_id'] = Utility::getAreaIdByName($row['customer_area']);
       $data['address'] = $row['customer_address'];
       $data['delivery_time'] = $row['delivery_time_in_hour'];
       $data['product_weight'] = $row['product_weight_in_kg'];
       $data['client_id'] = $client_id;
       $data['sender_address'] = $sender_address;
       $data['cash_amount'] = $row['cash_collection'];
       $data['client_reference'] = $row['client_reference'];
       $data['role_id'] = Auth::getUser()->role_id;
       OrderAction::save($data);
        
      }

    \Flash::success('Bulk Order uploaded Successfully');
     return Redirect::to('dashboard/shipments');
}
```

Is it possible to save multiple records with my approach? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try Model::create() method?

Comment: NO. should I try Model::create() instead of Model::save() ?

Comment: Yes, Please Try Model::create()